# How to create multiple entry widgets at once?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am making a data entry form as part of a GUI using python3 and tkinter.
I have created 10 data entry widgets which continue like below:

```
enter1 = Entry(self,textvariable = shots1)
enter1.place(x=1000, y=200)
enter2 = Entry(self, textvariable = shots2)
enter2.place(x=1000, y=250)
enter3 = Entry(self, textvariable = shots3)
enter3.place(x=1000, y=300)
enter4 = Entry(self, textvariable = shots4)
enter4.place(x=1000, y=350)
```

And I was wondering if there was a more efficient way - maybe using a for loop or class - in which I could create all of these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop. Widgets are no different than any other sort of object.

```
entries =[]
for i in range(5):
    entries.append(Entry(self, ...))
```

You almost never need to use textvariables, so I recommend not using them unless you need some of their unique features. You probably should also use `pack` or `grid` rather than `place`. `place` is generally good only for very specific edge cases.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but for some reason I keep getting an error message "List assignment index is out of range"

Comment: @Oceanescence: my mistake. I don't know what I was thinking -- I must have had a different language in mind. I've fixed the example. Thanks for commenting.